# Getting only time duration while calculating datetime difference

Tags: c#

I am calculating the difference between two times and i am getting negative values like Login time is "10-07-2017 09:28:00" and i am calculating the difference from "09:20:00" and i am getting "-3.23:52:00"...Where i am doing wrong?? This is my table...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2VzHPQzJdpmaXAxWG9KZ1o2U00/view

```
            string Logintime = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
            string Logoutime = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
            DateTime Logintimedt = Convert.ToDateTime(Logintime);
            DateTime Logoutimedt = Convert.ToDateTime(Logoutime);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today.AddHours(09).AddMinutes(20).AddSeconds(00);
            TimeSpan diff = (Logoutimedt - Logintimedt);
            TimeSpan delay = today-Logintimedt;
```

Comment: What's wrong with negative values? If you calculate `"10-07-2017 09:28:00" - "14-07-2017 09:20:00"` negative result it's right!

Comment: Are you sure that `Logoutime` time is properly set and not equal `DateTime.MinValue`. Can you show `Logoutime` variable?

Comment: can you provide value of Logintime, Logouttime?

Comment: @Dmitry There is no need of logoutime i have to calculate delay only with respect to logintime and only time difference i want...

Comment: can you set parameters in https://dotnetfiddle.net/hj8XWJ for more details

Comment: @MukeshChudasama Logintime:10-07-2017 09:28:00 and Logoutime:10-07-2017 17:16:22

Comment: check https://dotnetfiddle.net/X9p5jb it provide proper output.

Comment: @MukeshChudasama its giving delay=85.00:08:00 but it should be 08:00 only

Comment: @MukeshChudasama fiddler use MM/dd/yyyy format? but in example dd-MM-yyyy datetime format.

Comment: because you difference between 10-07-2017 09:28:00 & today (14-07-2017 09:20:00) is not only 8 minutes but 85 hrs 8 minutes. you need to set date as well if you want same day difference.

Comment: @MukeshChudasama is there not any way to get only time difference ??

Comment: @Dmitry : yes i corrected now, still login & today date is different which so its obvious that Logintimedt is smaller then today resulted in negative

Comment: @Simranjeet you need only time difference?

Comment: TimeSpan delay = today - Logintimedt; will make your delay positive but you should consider what time will be bigger as per your requirement

Comment: @Dmitry for delay i want only time difference..

Comment: @MukeshChudasama ya i have done that but how to get only time difference...

Comment: @Simranjeet i post answer, check it, and if this is what you want, please correct your question.

Comment: check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/lv7pGW

Comment: @MukeshChudasama thanks it worked...:)

Comment: posted ans below you can mark as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need time difference use `DateTime.TimeOfDay`

```
 TimeSpan diff = Logoutimedt.TimeOfDay - Logintimedt.TimeOfDay;
 TimeSpan delay = Logintimedt.TimeOfDay - today.TimeOfDay;
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9KKBfz

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string Logintime = "07-10-2017 09:28:00";
        string Logoutime = "07-10-2017 17:16:22 ";
        DateTime Logintimedt = Convert.ToDateTime(Logintime);
        DateTime Logoutimedt = Convert.ToDateTime(Logoutime);
        DateTime today = new DateTime(Logintimedt.Year, Logintimedt.Month, Logintimedt.Day, 9, 20, 00);
        TimeSpan diff = (Logoutimedt - Logintimedt);
        TimeSpan delay = Logintimedt - today;

        Console.WriteLine(diff);
        Console.WriteLine(delay);
    }
}
```